# Using angle grinder to shave wood?

Tags: wood, woodworking, carpentry

I have several 4-ft x 4"x4" pieces of wood, and I need to shave off a few millimeters of wood.

Can I use an [angle grinder](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/6ea5fb01-f95a-4eec-b060-904530e3ed37/svn/dewalt-angle-grinders-dwe402w-64_1000.jpg) for this? It doesn't have to be perfect, and I would only be shaving the millimeters from a 8-inch section of the 4-ft post.

Comment: How many is "a few"? 2? 3? 6?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, they work for coping and other sundry shaping. Then again, the fact that you can make a statue with a chainsaw doesn't mean that every carpenter ought to have on in their toolbox. A plane will give you a much flatter surface and probably be just as quick. I would suggest avoiding the grinder unless you can accept a wavy surface, since it will be difficult to keep the wheel flat and wood abrades much more quickly than metal or stone.

Speaking of chainsaws, I would suggest avoiding the chain-wrapped wheels for grinders in their entirety. I've never heard anyone suggest that they're a good idea. If you haven't seen them it's a grinder wheel with a chainsaw blade around the perimeter for sculpting wood.

A better solution is one of those abrasive flap wheels which mount sandpaper flaps to a grinder disk. It's not a replacement for belt sander but it's an economical solution if you already have a grinder.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Diablo-4-1-2-in-x-5-8-in-50-Grit-Grinder-Sander-Conversion-Kit-DCP045VGPS01G/202830887. This kit makes a grinder into a very aggressive sander

Comment: Flap wheels or the hard plastic backer pad (hd link above) with sandpaper can make a perfectly smooth surface and would be totally appropriate for the described task. (And as an aside, the chainsaw grinders are pure fun if faintly dangerous. They don't really figure in this conversation because they don't produce smooth surfaces.)

Comment: A course flappy disk works well I use them both on metal and wood with super results.+